React Native Image not updating the image on refresh or load
<Pressable onPress={pickImageAsync}>
  <Image 
    source={{ 
      uri: "http://10.0.0.196:3000/${props.name}_${props.mobile}/${props.name}_image1.png",
      cache:'reload'
    }}
    key={Math.random()}
    style={styles.image}
  />
</Pressable>

I am using express to serve the images however on changing the image in the same URL the image in react native is not getting updated, it seems it is only loading from the cache in Android. I have searched everywhere for a solution but still couldn't solve it. Kindly let me know if there is a solution to this issue.

It is a caching problem as you described. To force a cache refresh, consider including a unique query parameter in the image URL.
modified image uri with Math.random() as a unique query:
http://10.0.0.196:3000/${props.name}_${props.mobile}/${props.name}_image1.png?new=${Math.random()}
This should ensure it fetched a new image rather than rely on cache.
